# Jade iterator for value in input area

Tags: node.js, pug

i made some code in jade for a website. A for loop describe a table with x*tr. I want to use the iterator for my value to exchange the 1 in value=Json.Polygon_Point1.x_m. Whats my failure in this code? Thanks

```
      table
        tr
          td(style='width:200px;') Counter
          td
            input(id='', name='', type='text',  value=Json.PointCount)
        - for (var i=0; i<Json.PointCount; i++)
            tr
              td(style='width:200px;') Point.#{i}
              td(style='width:50px;')
                input(id='', name='', type='text',  value=Json.Polygon_Point +  #{i} +.x_m)
              td(style='width:50px;')
                input(id='', name='', type='text',  value='Hello' + {i})
```

Comment: Is Json.Polygon_Point an array?

Comment: It's an object from JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file).toString());

Answer (score 0):

If Json.Polygon_Point is an array or object where [i] is properties,

```
input(id='', name='', type='text',  value=Json.Polygon_Point[i].x_m)
```

Should do the trick. The trick is you can't mix jade's javscriptish definition of elements with #{} which interpolates a value to a string.